# Not sure how to find closure of a set A

Tags: real-analysis

suppose A is the set of all (a,b) \in [0,1] x [0,1] such that or p >= 2 (p prime) and m,n \in N such that (a,b) = (m/p, n/p). I have no idea how to go about finding the closure of A. I understand how to take a limit of a sequence but how do you come up with the sequence for the accumulation point?

Answer (score 0):

Since for every $\epsilon>0$ one can find a prime $p$ such that $1/p<\epsilon$ this means that the the set $\mathcal{Y}=\{m/p\leq1|\,m\in\mathbb{N},\,p\,\text{prime}\}$ is dense in the interval $[0,\,1]$: *every* $x\in[0,\,1]$ is such that the interval $(x-2/p,\,x+2/p)$ contains a point in $\mathcal{Y}$ when  you choose a prime big enough that$1/p<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. Therefore, the closure of $\mathcal{Y}$ is the whole interval $[0,\,1]$. So $[0,\,1]\times[0,\,1]$ is the closure of your set in the product topology (or simply the elementary "box" topology, which is the same for a finite product).